# Windows CLI: Show one of two processes with the same name

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

I have two processes with the same name

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql>tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq mysqld.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N"mysqld.exe"                                                                         

[4]mysqld.exe                    2868 Services                   0      3,072 K 
[5]mysqld.exe                    9964 Services                   0     37,680 K
```

The two processes of mysqld.exe are in separate folders. I want to check whether a certain mysqld.exe of a specific folder is running. Is this possible? Thank you.

I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Management Instrumentation can do what you are looking for, which is to display either the file path or the complete command line of the process:

```
wmic process where "name='mysqld.exe'" get ProcessID, ExecutablePath
or
wmic process where "name='mysqld.exe'" get ProcessID, ExecutablePath /FORMAT:LIST
```

The `CommandLine` option will show any start switches, such as a target data path or tcp ports

here is an example output for explorer.exe:

```
C:\Users\Richie>wmic process where "name='explorer.exe'" get ProcessID, ExecutablePath, CommandLine /FORMAT:LIST

CommandLine=C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
ExecutablePath=C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
ProcessId=3268

CommandLine=C:\Windows\explorer.exe /factory,{ceff45ee-c862-41de-aee2-a022c81eda92} -Embedding
ExecutablePath=C:\Windows\explorer.exe
ProcessId=4236


C:\Users\Richie>wmic process where "name='explorer.exe'" get ProcessID, ExecutablePath, CommandLine
CommandLine                                                                         ExecutablePath           ProcessId
C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE                                                             C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE  3268
C:\Windows\explorer.exe /factory,{ceff45ee-c862-41de-aee2-a022c81eda92} -Embedding  C:\Windows\explorer.exe  4236
```

Comment: also i notice a difference whether the cmd is administrative.

Comment: @barlop yes indeed, WMIC will still show the process ID, but the path and command line are on a different privilege level. If the application is run in the unelevated space it will show the details, otherwise you need cmd to run with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 1):

This in powershell

`PS C:\> gwmi Win32_Process | select Handle, CommandLine | format-list`

`PS C:\> gwmi Win32_Process -filter "name='chrome.exe'" | select Handle, CommandLine | format-list`

[image]

Comment: Also I notice that wmic process list / wmic process get processid, .... They give more results if done from an administrative cmd prompt, so, if not from an administrative prompt then wmic.. skips things like svchost who task manager shows has a username of system. tasklist shows the same number of processes regardless of administrative or not but as you've noticed, doesn't show the command line or folder. The powershell one gives the same full list of processes(i.e. including system processes), whether administrative or not and can show command line.